# Transcendence basis as subset of generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, transcendence-degree

Let $K \subset L = K(a_1,...,a_n)$ be a field extension finitely generated as $K$-algebra with
transcendence degree $\operatorname{Trdeg}_K(L):= m \le n$. It is well
known that the choice of a transcendence basis is hightly not unique.
The question is why it is always possible to find a transcendence basis
which is a *subset* of the set of *generators* $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ of $L$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if the set $a_1,\dots,a_n$ was algebraically independent that set already forms a transcendence basis for $L/K$. If not then there is some non-trivial polynomial $p$ over $K$ with $$p(a_1,\dots,a_n)=0$$
At least one of the $a_i$ has to appear on the left side. Wlog assume that $a_n$ appears there. Then $a_n$, and therefore also $L$, is algebraic over $K(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})$. Now continue in the same way until you are left with algebraically independent elements $a_1,\dots,a_{n-i}$, so that the other elements $a_{n-i+1},\dots,a_n$ are algebraic over $K(a_1,\dots,a_{n-i})$. Then $\{a_1,\dots,a_{n-i}\}$ will be your transcendence base.
Note that this argument heavily relied on the fact that we have a *finite* set (otherwise the process might not stop). Here is another argument (which is actually not that different) which also works in the infinite case:
Let $S$ be the set of all algebraically independent subsets of $A:=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$. Note that this set is not empty as $\emptyset\in S$. As $S$ is finite $S$ has a maximal element $B$ with respect to the inclusion (in the infinite case we would need to invoke Zorn's lemma here to get the existence of a maximal element). I claim that this $B$ is a transcendence base for $L/K$. By definition $B$ is algebraically independent. Now for any $a\in A\setminus B$ by maximality of $B$ the set $B\cup \{a\}$ is algebraically independent. It follows that there is a non-trivial polynomial $p$ over $K$ with $$p(B,a)=0$$
As $B$ is algebraically independent $a$ has to appear on the left side, so $a$ is algebraic over $K(B)$. It follows that $L=K(A)$ is algebraic over $K(B)$, so $B$ is indeed a transcendence base.

You might see that the reasoning above is very similar to that in linear algebra when dealing with bases of vector spaces. The principle that is behind these two things is the notion of a [Dependence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependence_relation).

Comment: so implicitely have in both cases to use also the uniqueness and
additivity of trans number ($L/M/K$ extension, then $trans(L(K)=
trans(L/M)+trans(M/K)$), right?

Comment: No, the only thing I used here was the definition of a transcendence base.

Comment: Could you say which definition of a transcendence base you used? I know this
one: For an extension $L/K$ a trans base is the 
largest algebraically independent subset $S \subset L$ over $K$.
You showed that the set of generators $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ of 
$L = K(a_1,...,a_n)$ contains subset $\{a_1,...,a_{n-i}\}$ beeing 
maximal in $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ with property that the $a_1,...,a_{n-i}$
are algebraically independent over $K$. Then one could ask why there not exist a 
$m \in L \backslash \{a_1,...,a_{n-i}\}$
with $\{a_1,...,a_{n-i}, m\}$ still algebraically independent over $K$.

Comment: I think that using only the definition of transcendence base I quoted
thats not obvious. Except we apply additionally $trans(L(K)= trans(L/M)+trans(M/K)$ to 
the the tower $K \subset K(a_1,...,a_{n-i}) \subset  K(a_1,...,a_n)=L$
and observe that as you said that by choice of the $\{a_1,...,a_{n-i}\}$
the extension $K(a_1,...,a_{n-i})/K$ is pure transcendental
of degree $n-i$ and $L/K(a_1,...,a_{n-i})$ algebraic. But now to deduce
that the $\{a_1,...,a_{n-i}\}$ form a transendence base of $L/K$
we have to use $trans(L(K)= trans(L/M)+trans(M/K)$, or not? Or
did I misunderstood your idea?

Comment: A subset $A\subset L$ is a transcendence base of $L/K$ iff $A$ is algebraically independent and $L/K(A)$ is algebraic. This is equivalent to the definition you mentioned.  Note that if $b\in L$ and $b\notin A$, then $b$ is algebraic over $K(A)$, so in particular $A\cup\{b\}$ is algebraically dependent. Therefore $A$ is a maximal algebraically independent subset. On the other hand if $A$ is such a maximal subset, then by maximality every $b\in L$ will be algebraic over $K(A)$, so $A$ is transcendence base in the above sense.